# Defining RESTful from clients perspective

Tags: rest, restful-url

Can I just assume if I need to do a HTTP POST to a url to get back a string of data (JSON or otherwise) that it is a RESTful API? Or is there another term for a general api like this?

I understand that there is probably more behind the scenes on the server that could determine if it is a *true* RESTful API, but as far as the client can tell, *are there any other characteristics*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be *part* of a RESTful API; it certainly doesn't sound incompatible with one. If it was RESTful, you'd also have extensive use of HTTP GET for doing reading of things (with content negotiation to determine the format — the representation — to deliver the values as), proper use of HTTP verbs for the true meaning (not everything is a POST!) and HTTP error codes for their meanings (not everything is a 200!) and there would be hypertext linking to allow everything to be located.

REST is just a way of writing a rather dynamic website. That implements a service.